# Attribute to force member variable to be non-null at call site

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I'm currently switching over my existing codebase to use nullable reference types, and I was wondering if there's a way of saying "this member function should only be called if a member variable is non-null". A highly simplified example would be this:

```
class MyClass
{
   public string? myString = null;

   [MemberNotNullWhen(returnValue: true, nameof(myString))]
   public bool IsStringNotNull()
   {
       return myString is not null;
   }

   public string GetNonNullableString()
   {
       return myString;
   }

   public void PrintMyString()
   {
       if(IsStringNotNull())
       {
           Console.WriteLine(GetNonNullableString());    
       }
   }
}
```

At the moment the static analysis complains that GetNonNullableString() might return a null reference, but the compiler should know when calling that function that myString is non-null. Is there an attribute I can put on GetNonNullableString() to say this function should only be called in places where the compiler knows that myString is non-null?

Obviously I can add a null check inside that function, but I'd rather do it further up the call chain.

Comment: Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) article of the MSDocs. It contains a definition for each attribute regarding null-state static analysis.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like there isn't much in the way of pre-conditions currently, which feels like a place we could do with more attributes.